# R: How to divide several columns into equal and equivalent parts, reduce the number of columns, and reallocate data?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```r
"ID" "condition" "E_01" "E_02" "E_03" "E_04"...
"ID01" "cond1"    0.1    0.2    0.1    N/A
"ID01" "cond2"    N/A    N/A    N/A    0.1
"ID01" "cond3"    N/A    N/A    N/A    N/A
"ID02" "cond1"    0.1    0.2    0.1    N/A
...
```

where the `E_XY` labels continue until `N`.

If we assume `N=9` I would like to first split `N` into equal and equivalent parts, for example 3, to retrieve `"T_01", "T_02", "T_03"` three times, and next, reallocate the data to get rid of the `N/A`s as illustrated in the desired output.
(`"E_01","E_04","E_07"` all belong to `"T_01"`;  `"E_02","E_05","E_08"` all belong to `"T_02"` etc.)

Desired output:

```r
"ID" "condition" "T_01" "T_02" "T_03"
"ID01" "cond1"    0.1    0.2    0.1
"ID01" "cond2"    0.1    0.2    0.1
"ID01" "cond3"    0.1    0.2    0.1
"ID02" "cond1"    0.1    0.2    0.1
...
```

Does anyone know a smart way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, try this with `split.default` -

```
cols <- grep('E_', names(df))
N <- 3
result <- cbind(df[-cols], sapply(split.default(df[cols], 1:N), rowSums, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint to use split.default! I think I can solve my problem now.